# Sparkline in SSRS report not showing zero values

Tags: reporting-services

In my SSRS report I am displaying the Sparkline at the row level which is numeric data. I have 13 columns, some of which will have zero as the value. For these, the sparkline doesn't appear.

For example

```
col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 
-----+------+------+------
 0   |  0   |  1   |  0     ---> the sparkline doesnt show up or it shows 1. 
 4   |  4   |  1   |  2     ---> the sparkline shows up correctly.
```

I even put an expression for forcing the value zero in the value field by:

```
iif(Field!.ID.value=0,0,Field.ID.Value)
```

Also, I have set the EmptyPointValue=0 from average.

Is there a way to correctly show the sparkline for value as Zero?

Comment: You are aware that as shown above your `iif` statement has an extra `.` which means it shouldn't work?  It should be `iif(Field!ID.value=0,0,Field.ID.Value)`.  Also this statement seems a bit pointless as it's saying if it's zero make it zero... would it not be better to check if he value was `IsNothing()`?

Comment: Can you share an image of the current output?

Comment: Yes, Isnothing condition was added later. Thanks for the suggest!

Comment: Did that solve the problem then? If so you can answer your own question (below) with the solution so other people can reference it in the future